# when running the xcode project (generated through cmake) on the iPad. error occurred: "ipad_test is not an ipa file"

Tags: xcode, ipad, cmake

I create a CMakeLists.txt and main.cpp as following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)  
project(YourProjectName)


set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT "iphoneos")


set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64")


add_executable(ipad_test
    main.cpp
)

set_target_properties(ipad_test PROPERTIES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY "1,2"  # iPad
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM "xxx"  
)
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 
    printf("========test====\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And I used "cmake -G Xcode ." command to create a xcode project. But when I run this xcode project on the iPad, I am prompted with the following error:
[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? thanks a lot!

BTW: use cmake to create xcode project, and run on ipad. this is what I want.